# Slicing a List + Converting a Nested List into a Dictionary (+ Pairing a List of Values to the key)

Tags: python

I previously asked a question here, about how to slice strings and using them as keys and values, and people helped me to come up with a solution which is below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
    ]
dc = defaultdict(str)

for item in lst:
    x, *y = item.split('-')
    dc[x] = y
    
print(dc)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'Macbook Air ': [' 13inch Model'], 'Iphone13 ': [' Max Pro 65GB Model'], 'Airpod2': []})
```

however, what if it ends up generating the same key and I wanted to have a list of values paired within the same key name?

for example:

```
lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max 128GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
    ]
```

and output will be looking like:

```
defaultdict(<class 'str'>, {'Macbook Air ': [' 13inch Model'], 'Iphone13 ': [' Max Pro 65GB Model', 'Pro 128GB Model'], 'Airpod2': []})
```

I assumed it will automatically stored more than one values but it only paired with the first key and value and others with the same key name disappeared.

Comment: Just change the default dict to default to a list: `dc = defaultdict(list)`, then add elements to the list `dc[x].extend(y)`. The way you are doing `x, *y =` suggests you anticipate more than one ` - ` in the strings; is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a `defaultdict` of lists rather than strings:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [
    'Macbook Air - 13inch Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max Pro 65GB Model',
    'Iphone13 - Max 128GB Model',
    'Airpod2'
    ]
dc = defaultdict(list)

for item in lst:
    x, *y = item.split('-')
    dc[x].extend(y)
```

gives you a `dc` with the following contents:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
    'Macbook Air ': [' 13inch Model'],
    'Iphone13 ': [' Max Pro 65GB Model', ' Max 128GB Model'],
    'Airpod2': []
})
```